# Gitlab-CI with Gitlab setup, self-hosted

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have setup Gitlab in ubuntu server, it's working fine. I access Gitlab by url `http://123.456.789.100` and Gitlab login details

```
 username:admin@local.host 
 password:123456
```

Then I wanted to set Gitlab CI for test the code before it merge. I have done with setting Gitlab CI by using the link. I have done setting up every thing except Runners. While set `ssh git@<your gitlab url>` in Runner I face error

```
 ssh git@123.456.789.100
 it prompts me for password
```

git@123.456.789.100's password:
I entered password(123456) of gitlab's that I used to enter into gitlab server, then I have this error

```
Permission denied please try again
```

But I got Gitlab CI web interface by `http://123.456.789.100:8081`(I did set Gitlab-ci to listen on 8081 port). Then I entered Gitlab server's username and password as admin@local.host and 123456, I got Invalid credentials.

What would be the wrong I made?

Comment: Why are you trying to ssh into the gitlab instance from the runner?

Comment: As @Suever mentioned before I don't know neither why are you trying to ssh into gitlab from the runner. When registering a new runner, it will ask for the gitlab instance url, then the token and other options. Here is the link to the official documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#gnulinux

Comment: I believe it should be gitlab token instead of password.

Answer (score 5):

When you put `git@` in the ssh it’s actually trying to use the git user on the machine that is running GitLab (rather than some GitLab controlled user).

The easiest fix for this would be to create an [SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) on the runner in question and then [add that SSH key to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html).  That will allow the runner to access the GitLab instance and clone and repositories you need.

For more help getting started, see [this page on Configuring GitLab runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html).